# Laravel Teamwork invite someone without an account

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with the Teamwork module:

https://github.com/mpociot/teamwork

The module is set up to send invitations to users (ie. people who already have an account) to join the inviter. I'd like to invite potential users who don't yet have an account, to allow them to create one and join the team in one step.

This is the current acceptInvite function in the Teamwork AuthController:

```
public function acceptInvite($token)
{
    $invite = Teamwork::getInviteFromAcceptToken($token);
    if (!$invite) {
        abort(404);
    }

    if (auth()->check()) {
        Teamwork::acceptInvite($invite);
        return redirect()->route('teams.index');
    } else {
        session(['invite_token' => $token]);
        return redirect()->to('login');
    }
}
```

So I've changed it to redirect to the registration page instead of the login page. Then this is the create function in the RegisterController:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user =  User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

    ]);

    $id= $user->id; // Get current user id

    $token = session('invite_token');
    $invite = Teamwork::getInviteFromAcceptToken($token);

    Debugbar::info($invite);

    if ($invite) {

        return $user;
        Teamwork::acceptInvite($invite);

    } else {

        //create a team
        ...
    }
}
```

Debugbar::info($invite) in the above code produces this in the debugbar:

```
#original: array:9 [
  "id" => 4
  "user_id" => 13
  "team_id" => 11
  "type" => "invite"
  "email" => "testuser4@test.com"
  "accept_token" => "ddde37c58aa6376533fa289c89bee32e"
  "deny_token" => "450b433bd51b2520a78c24563e8c81c9"
  "created_at" => "2017-10-08 20:58:45"
  "updated_at" => "2017-10-08 20:58:45"
]
```

But the invite is not accepted. I know that if($invite) is working because a new team is not created. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://www.teamwork.com/partner/vclgpvmusj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a `return $user` before calling `Teamwork::acceptInvite($invite)`. Swap this lines and it should work:

```
if ($invite) {

    Teamwork::acceptInvite($invite);
    return $user;

} else {

    //create a team
    ...
}
```

Calling `return` inside a function will end its execution. See more on the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php).

If after swapping this lines you get the next error:

```
FatalThrowableError Call to a member function attachTeam() on null
```

Is probably because you are trying to accept an invite before the user is authenticated.

You can try authenticating it before calling `Teamwork::acceptInvite($invite)` like this:

```
if ($invite) {

    Auth::attempt([
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => $data['password']
    ]);

    Teamwork::acceptInvite($invite);

    return $user;

} else {

    //create a team
    ...
}
```

Comment: The reason I did that was that I was getting the following error:  `FatalThrowableError 
Call to a member function attachTeam() on null` 
This is caused by the `Teamwork::acceptInvite($invite)` line and according to a google search is due to no user being loaded.

Comment: That's probably because the user it not yet authenticated. I'm updating my answer with some suggestion for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```php
if ($invite) {
    Teamwork::acceptInvite($invite);
    return $user;
}
```